# How to show Navigating away alert based on locale option

Tags: javascript

i am using a navigating alert when user leaves the page without saving data using the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  window.onbeforeunload = function(e){

    if(dataChnaged()){  

     return '' ;          
    }
  }
});
```

i am getting like this in fire fox.. i need to show this alert based on locale. is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? A different language? Also you mean `if (!dataChanged())` and why not use jQuery for both event handlers?

Comment: The language of the browser UI you will find in `navigator.language`, so that could be a starting point. But I can’t really see why you would wanna do that anyway – I mean, your page is in a certain language, right? So if the user understands that, he should be able to understand your message in the same language I suppose. And if you are serving different language versions of your site, by user choice or automatically, then you should have mechanism for content translation in place already.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing you can come using  javascript is a confirm box

```
if (confirm('Your question')) { 
 // do things if OK
}
```

if you want customization you should simple display a html element that is hidden on whatever event you desire. With some absolute position and css, it could look pretty much like anything you want.

Comment: could you explain in more detail what it is that you want to have done?

Comment: i want to display an alert to user if the user leaves the page without saving data. the alert should consists of ok and cancel similar to the above image..on clicking on cancel the user have to be in the same page.i need to show the  the alert in different languages based on locale